# How to get content from external javascript file without extra request?

Tags: javascript, http, dom

For running ads on a webpage, I'm placing a simple function inside the dom.

```
Dom: 
addAd(1234);


function addAd(id) {
    ...
    noAd = false;
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://foo.bar/ads/' + id '"></scr'+'ipt>');
}
```

This will then write the script tag to the DOM and execute the remote script.
However the script may actually not be a script but contain noAd = true in case there is no ad to be served.

Further on, I'm removing or adding stuff to the DOM depending on the noAd variable.

However, in case the script file contains noAd = true; it does not update the variable I can access with my browser.

How can I get the contents of that file to overwrite my noAd variable? I can not change the remote file or it's content.

Any ideas?

(Making a XMLHttpRequest on the file to check it's contents is not possible because of the x-domain policies JS has. I can not use jQuery for this.)

Comment: Apparently, it's a syntax error - both the JS string literals and the HTML tag. Remove `>'"`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, somehow I broke the code by copy-pasting it. :) Corrected the mistake.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*may actually not be a script*"? What exactly is it, would it produce a syntax error so that `noAd=true` is not executed? Btw, are you sure that `noAd` is a global variable?